# How do I create a file with a ruby gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

My gem requires rails. Is it possible to create and add a file to the lib directory when the gem is installed so that the user can add their own code to that file without creating the file on their own?

Comment: It would be highly unorthodox. What code might a user want to put in the file? Config? Constants? Data? Actual ruby code?

Comment: On further thought, it's not just unorthodox, it's hazardous! A gem can normally be updated with `gem update my_gem` but if the user has written a file into the gem source, it gets lost in the update. There's probably a better solution. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What I would recommend instead of this is creating a rails generator for this use case - https://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html

Then end users of the library will be able to generate this file using `rails g`

Comment: @LesNightingill the generation of a file in the project is not unorthodox at all, actually it is common place in a lot of instances. e.g. `RSpec`, `SimpleForm`, `Devise`, etc. all have installation mechanisms which generate files in different directories of the project source code.

Comment: @engineersmnky yes of course there is much precedenet for config files located in the project... but not in the directory of the gem itself, as OP has asked

Comment: @LesNightingill maybe we are just interpreting it differently I read this as the lib directory in the rails project. OP can you please clarify if you meant the lib directory of the gem or the lib directory of the rails project?

Comment: @engineersmnky as I re-read the OP, I think your interpretation is reasonable. It may be me that misunderstood!

Comment: @engineersmnky yes, correct you can add as an answer if youd like

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at [creating-your-first-generator](https://creating-your-first-generator)

First creates an initializer with a file named `initializer.rb` inside `config/initializers`. The first step is to create a file at lib/generators/initializer_generator.rb with the following content:

```
  class InitializerGenerator < Rails::Generators::Base
    def create_initializer_file
      create_file "config/initializers/initializer.rb", <<~RUBY
        # Add initialization content here
      RUBY
    end
  end
```

Our new generator follows a straightforward structure: it inherits from Rails::Generators::Base and contains a single method definition. When this generator is called, each public method within it is executed sequentially in the order of their definition. In our method, we utilize create_file, a utility that generates a file at the specified destination with the provided content.

```
bin/rails generate initializer
```

When a generator is namespaced, like ActiveRecord::Generators::ModelGenerator, Rails can typically derive a suitable description. However, in certain cases, this may not be possible. To address this issue, there are two approaches we can take. The first method involves adding a description by using the desc method within our generator:

```
class InitializerGenerator < Rails::Generators::Base
  desc "This generator creates an initializer file at config/initializers"
  def create_initializer_file
    create_file "config/initializers/initializer.rb", <<~RUBY
      # Add initialization content here
    RUBY
  end
end
```